# The output is showing null

Tags: java

So I am a beginner in programming and I have a project in class that asks me to make a bridge hand and deal them out to four players. One of the tasks asks me to print out a shuffled deck, however, when I try to print it out, it outputs 52 null statements instead of the shuffled deck. Can someone please help me figure this out. Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Card {

   public static String[] SUITS = {"Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades"};
   public static String[] RANKS = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"};

   public static String[]deck = new String[52];

   public static String[] createDeck() { // initializes and creates deck

      for(int i = 0; i < RANKS.length ; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < SUITS.length ; j++) {

            deck[SUITS.length * i + j] = RANKS[i] + " of " + SUITS[j];
         }
      }
      return deck; 
   }

   public static void shuffleDeck(String[]deck) { //shuffles deck created from array
      int n = deck.length;

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

         int r = i + (int)(Math.random() * (n-i));

         String temp = deck[r];
         deck[r] = deck[i]; 
         deck[i] = temp;

         System.out.println(deck[i]);
      }  
   }   

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Card.shuffleDeck(deck);

   }
```

Comment: I would recommend making `deck` a local variable instead of a static variable - it would make this kind of error much harder to run into!

Comment: Deck should honestly just be a separate `Class` that creates the deck using the `Card` class when you do `Deck d = new Deck()`,  I recommend learning how to use OOP rather than just declare everything as a `static` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `createDeck()` call in your `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    createDeck();
    shuffleDeck(deck);
}
```

Because the following statement only initializes the `deck` array with `52` `null` values:

```
public static String[]deck = new String[52];
```

You need to fill the `deck` array with actual values to display them properly. And you can safely mark `createDeck()` as `void` because you don't need to return `deck` array as it is declared as `static` which will be accessible anyway. Same is the case with `shuffleDeck()` method, you don't need to pass the `static` array, it will be accessible.

Or you could go with another approach in which `deck` array is declared as a local variable and it is passed to these methods as an argument.